# sql- joining two tables but preserving all the columns from first table

Tags: mysql, sql

i have two tables and im using inner join. when i join the second tables first field(id) gets left out because im joining on the second field of the second table and the first field of the first table. is there a way to preserve the first field of the second table?

Comment: What does your query look like?

Comment: what do you mean with "second tables first field(id) gets left out "? you should to detail more

Comment: What do you mean by 'preserve' - assuming a successful join you can have any columns from either table that you want.

Comment: TABLE1_NAME INNER JOIN ON TABLE2_NAME WHERE (TABLE1_NAME.cooks_id = TABLE2.id);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using right outer join - it preserves the unmatched rows from the second(right) table.

Comment: Hey are you Danial Cook from the tv show. You may be my long lost son!

Answer (score 0):

Try getting the fields with alias, such as:
SELECT table1.field as myfirstfield, table2.otherfield as myotherfield... FROM table1 INNER JOIN table2 ON (condition)